# Freemarker get current timestamp

Tags: java, timestamp, freemarker

How can I get the current timestamp (number of seconds since 01/01/1970) in a freemarker file? I know the `.now` var but I didn't figure how to get a basic timestamp format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`?long`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html) operator:

```
.now?long
```

for milliseconds, or

```
${.now?long / 1000}
```

for seconds